# Why, when using an ammeter in a circuit powered by DC, does the current sometimes read as negative?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrons, electric-current, charge

Conventional current is the rate of flow of charge, defined as:
$$I=\frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta t}$$

$\Delta t$ can only ever be positive, so for $I$ to be negative $\Delta Q$ must be negative.

However, if the (conventional) flow of charge is from positive to negative, and electron flow is from negative to positive, then for $\Delta Q$ to be negative the flow of charge must be in the reverse direction, which means that the electrons are also travelling in the reverse direction from positive to negative.

How is this possible?

Comment: Ampmeters measure current by measuring the voltage across a resistor. Therefore, if you swap the two connectors, I expect your ampmeter will change sign. Correct?

Comment: So do ammeters have a dedicated positive connector and a dedicated negative connector, so if you connect an ammeter the wrong way the current will be negative? I guess that makes sense.

Comment: I don't know, if this is true for all (!) ampmeters. However, you should just check this on the ampmeter you are currently using. <i>Bottom line:</i> I don't think this is physics, but merely a convention of the company producing your ampmeter.

Comment: The idea of counting charges to get a $\Delta Q$ is  conceptual, to provide a definition. As @Semoi points out, most ammeters are actually voltage-responsive devices.  There may be some highly sensitive charge-based (induction??) meters, but they are not found in student-level labs.

Comment: @Semoi - I am not sure what ammeters  you use but the ones I use measure the current through a circuit when in current-mode (i.e., you break the circuit and send the current through the device).  In voltage-mode, they measure the voltage across a resistor (i.e., the cables do not interrupt the circuit).  Regardless, current does have a direction so yes it does matter which cable is connected first (i.e., from high-to-low potential).

Comment: @honeste_vivere: Are you sure about that? How do you think the meter measures "current".  I know about two methods: (1) "Cheap" ampmeters measure the voltage drop above a well-known resistor (2) A fancy ampmeter in our lab used a Hall sensor and a "counter-current": The counter-current was adjusted to null the magnetic field @ the Hall sensor. Simultaneously the voltage drop of the counter-current across a resistor was measured.  So bottom line: The voltage dop across a resistor was measured.

Comment: The simplest (Weston-type) ammeter directs most of the incoming current into a shunt resistance, leaving the rest (of the order of 1mA) to go through a coil. The coil is in a magnetic field, so the current through it makes it rotate and moves the attached needle. Whether this is measuring the current directly or whether it is measuring the voltage across the coil is very much in the eye of the beholder. It is true that the resistance of the coil (as well as that of the shunts) has to be calibrated pretty accurately for a "good" meter.